# trouble comparing a list to an integer

Tags: python-3.x

this is my current code.  it takes a list and compars it to an integer, and it produces a newe list of thee numbers greatr than the integer "thresh".  however right now it's not doing that.

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8]
thresh = 4

def biggerThan(a, thresh):
  newList = []
  for i in a:
    if i> thresh:
      newList.append(i)
  if len(newList) == 0:
    return None
  else:
    return newList
  
biggerThan([1,2,3,4],4)
```

i have tried to pre-declare a and thresh and i called the arbuments after the def of the function.

Comment: Your code works fine; there are no numbers in `[1, 2, 3, 4]` bigger than `4` and so it is returning `None`. Try `biggerThan([1,2,3,4],4) is None` to see this

Comment: Did you mean to use the list `a`? i.e: `biggerThan(a,4)`. It's not clear why you included it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine!
You just need to use the variable `a` which is `a = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8]` while calling your function.

`biggerThan(a,4)`